# How to convert a function of keplerian elements to a function of equinoctial elements?

Tags: orbit, orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements

I need to convert the Keplerian orbital elements to the equinoctial elements and then use the converted elements"equinoctial" in the function "d" below. To do this, first, I converted the Keplerian elements to equinoctial elements (a,h,k,p,q,lamda)  using the formula in the attached picture, BUT I need to know what is the equinoctial elements that correspond to each of e,i,w,omega so that I can replace each keplerian elements in the function "d" with the equinoctial element.

d= Sin[omega]* Cos[w]2 +[w] + Cos[omega] *Cos[i]* Sin[w - Omega]

[image]

Comment: Formulas can be written in MathJax for better readability. Here's a tutorial about it: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Are you sure that the $w$ summand in the middle is correct? Also, are there variables $w$, $omega$, and $Omega$?

Comment: Its not very clear what you want.  Perhaps you want to calculate the keplerian elements from a, h, k, p q and lambda